# Cast to Swift.Int from a Swift.Int as a generic fails surprisingly

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I have a complicated function that tries to cast arbitrary incoming parameters to known types. I get this error.

```
Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Int' (0x100a73aa8) to 'Swift.Int' (0x1002b7fb8).
```

Here's a rough outline of the function:

```
public func convert <A, T>(a:A, _ t:T.Type) -> T? {

print(t)  // Int
print(T.self)  // Int
print(T.self == Int.self)  // False. But why?

...

// Well I got a little hacky since the rest of the checks failed...
if "\(T.self)" == "Int" {
        let ret = Int(a as! NSNumber)
        print(ret) // 6, reports as an Int
        return ret as! T
}
```

Im passing an NSNumber. It works when the code is in the same project.

Its worth noting the types are being passed in from application code and this is in framework code. When I run it locally it works no problem. Could it be that the framework code is referring to a different type in memory than the application code?

Also worth mentioning: this is a project with iOS and OSX targets. I only see the error below when running the OSX target.

`objc[24993]: Class _TtC6AppKit15REPLApplication is implemented in both /Users/Damouse/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FabAgainstBackend-ajqzosbfxnphgjaabtlaawsjsywj/Build/Products/Debug/Riffle.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libswiftAppKit.dylib and /Users/Damouse/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FabAgainstBackend-ajqzosbfxnphgjaabtlaawsjsywj/Build/Products/Debug/FabAgainstBackend. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. This is an OSX app with a Cocoapod that contains Swift code. In order to get the app to compile, I had to set "Contains embedded swift code" to Yes.

This lets the code compile, but gives me the "Which one is undefined." error. I believe the swift lib is being linked against twice and thus the type referenced in the framework code is different than the type passed in from the application code. The "solution":

```
if "\(T.self)" == "Int" {
        let ret = Int(a as! NSNumber)
        return unsafeBitCast(ret, T.self)
}
```

... which is barely duct tape. It works, but it makes my inner kitten sad.